# Adding a data type as a function parameter

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

What is the difference between the main function with a data type vs one with no parameters?

```
int main(void) {
     cout << "File " << endl;
}
```

```
int main() {
     cout << "File " << endl;
}
```

Comment: None. The second is an abbreviation of the first.

Comment: In a very old dialect of C, so called K&R, `void f(void)` meant "function that takes no parameters" while `void f()` meant "function whose number and types of parameters is unspecified, automatically deduced from the call". C++ never allowed that - `void f()` always meant "function taking no parameters" (I'm not sure if modern C still supports the "unspecified parameters" meaning). `void f(void)` is accepted as equivalent to `void f()`, for compatibility with C code.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Was there any `void` in the old K&R to begin with?

Comment: @kirjosieppo That's my recollection. I must admit I don't have any literature from that period anymore that I could use to confirm. It must have had a `void*` at least, I'd think.